# How do you get the content of a MindMeister Map using the V2 API

Tags: api, mindmapping, mindmap

I would like to read the content of a MindMeister mindmap using their API.

In V1 (**now deprecated**) you could get an XML response via `mm.maps.getMap`
 and that would return data nodes in the mind map like this [getMap](https://www.mindmeister.com/developers/explore_method?method=mm.maps.getMap) !

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<rsp stat="ok">
   <ideas>
      <idea>
         <!-- This is a Root Node with the label 'Freemind map' -->
         <note />
         <icon />
         <style>000000</style>
         <closed>false</closed>
         <parent />
         <modifiedat>2007-06-20 06:40:04</modifiedat>
         <pos>
            <y>0</y>
            <x>0</x>
         </pos>
         <link />
         <rank />
         <modifiedby>3</modifiedby>
         <id>2490</id>
         <title>Freemind map</title>
      </idea>
      <idea>
         <!-- This is a Child Node hanging from 'Freemind map' with the label 'This is a test' -->
         <note />
         <icon>idea,status_ok</icon>
         <style>000000</style>
         <closed>false</closed>
         <parent>2490</parent>
         <modifiedat>2007-06-20 06:40:04</modifiedat>
         <pos>
            <y>125</y>
            <x>-39</x>
         </pos>
         <link />
         <rank>0</rank>
         <modifiedby>3</modifiedby>
         <id>2491</id>
         <title>This is a test</title>
      </idea>
   </ideas>
</rsp>
```

In V2, you don't get the content of the map, instead, you just get the metadata, e.g. title, user_id and created date but there is NO data which seems quite pointless.

Here is an example of what https://developers.mindmeister.com/docs/maps-as-file returns

```
{
    "id": 28265156,
    "user_id": 443040,
    "root_id": 1053370534,
    "revision": 195,
    "description": null,
    "not_final": false,
    "import_origin": null,
    "view_counter": 0,
    "rating": 0,
    "sum_rating": 0,
    "num_rating": 0,
    "subshare": true,
    "created_at": "2018-03-07T21:41:12.000Z",
    "updated_at": "2018-03-18T21:24:37.000Z",
    "category_id": null,
    "language": "en",
    "allow_copy_export": true,
    "is_template": false,
    "public_license": null,
    "featured": null,
    "theme_id": 935074,
    "share_token": null,
    "sharing": 0,
    "layout": 0,
    "public_listing": true,
    "copy_counter": 0,
    "voting": false,
    "title": "keyword-research"
}
```

Here is the data I am trying to access in the Mind Map

[image: Mind Map Data Example - MindMeister]

I have also tried the V1 API and you can't run any of the test harnesses.

When you try to run a V1 test harness with valid credentials you are told that V1 is deprecated so testing is a real challenge.

I get that V1 will be deprecated after V2 is finished, but can it at least be re-activated until V2 exists?

[image: V1 Deprecated for MindMeister]

Comment: I don't understand what your question is.

Comment: I will reword it then

Answer (score 3):

The API v2 doesn't provide this endpoint yet. It should be added in the near future. Until then you still can use the endpoint of v1. The API v1 will not be disabled until API v2 is complete, even if it's already deprecated.

Comment: I have updated my question based on your message here, because even the V1 API has a big challenge in it's usage.

Comment: The API v1 had a bug with the test requests. This is fixed now.